# Fill ImageAdapter with Int[]

Tags: android, database, image, integer

**What I've Done**

---

I have created a GridView in my layout. This GridView I'd like to fill over my ImageAdapter I've created of the Google Documentations: [Hello GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

The picturepath to my pictures, did i save into my datbase and I'd like to fill it over it. Because in my Datbase everything is a String I wrote in my Activity a short function which changes the String[] into a Int[], but I can't acces that over my ImageAdapter. Afterwards I applied the changes that Mrs. Nikita told me. Also I changed to lil thing to change the String[] to an int[] (is working now).

**Question**

---

What do I need to change to get the Int[] to my ImageAdapter that it imports my pictures and that they are shown in the GrindView.
Now I have a Nullpointer Exception at:

```
public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
```

**The Code:**

---

This is the Code of my SmileyConfigActivity.java:

```
package de.retowaelchli.filterit;

import de.retowaelchli.filterit.database.SmileyDBAdapter;
import de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats.ImageAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class SFilterConfigActivity extends Activity {

    //Variablen deklarieren
    private String name;
    private String keyword;
    private Integer[] info;
    private SmileyDBAdapter SmileyHelper;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sfilter_config);

      SmileyHelper = new SmileyDBAdapter(this);

      getImages();

    }


public Integer[] getImages(){



    SmileyHelper.open();

    Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getAllSmileys();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] picture = new String[] { SmileyDBAdapter.INFO };

    int i;
    for (i=0;i< picture.length-1;i++) {
        info[i]=Integer.parseInt(picture[i+1]);

    }

    SmileyHelper.close();

    //Hier wird die Grindview gefüllt
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.SmileyGrind);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, info));

    return info;

}



public void onClickSConfigSave(View v){

    EditText edtTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SFConfigName);
    EditText edtTextKeyword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SFConfigKeyword);

    name = edtTextName.getText().toString();
    keyword = edtTextKeyword.getText().toString();

    final Intent i = new Intent(this, SmileyActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is the Code of my ImageAdapter.java:

```
    package de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageIds) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = imageIds;
    }

    //This Guy down here is giving me the NullpointerExcpetion now
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }


    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
}
```

And this is how i store the pictures to the Datbase (I only save to place where they are located):

```
    int drawableID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("angel", "drawable", getPackageName());
    iv.setImageResource(drawableID);

    String info = String.valueOf(drawableID);

    mDbHelper.open();

    mDbHelper.createSmiley("You have received a heavenly message", info);
    mDbHelper.close();
```

This is the Error-Log I get:

```
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.retowaelchli.filterit/de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.stats.ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageAdapter.java:25)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:131)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity.getImages(SFilterConfigActivity.java:54)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity.onCreate(SFilterConfigActivity.java:30)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
10-04 13:26:25.776: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10099):     ... 11 more
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: I don't quite understand. In `getImages` method you get all images from DB and convert to ints. Why can't you use this array and pass it to `ImageAdapter` as constructor argument?

Comment: i tried this, but it dosn't work. I imported my Activity like this `import de.retowaelchli.filterit.SFilterConfigActivity;`afterwards i extendedit like this `private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        SFilterConfigActivity.getImages();   
    };` But I didn't work I just became this error: _Change getImages to static Intger[] getImages, if I do that it doesn't work..

Comment: so please misses Beloglazov, what am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of pertinent info missing here but if you fill in the blanks I will update the answer.  First problem is what are you retrieving in your getAllSmileys function?

What you need to understand is that a cursor is like a memory table of results.  So you need to tell the cursor which record to fetch from by using move commands otherwise it is uniniitilaized.  So assuming your smilleys are stored in the SmileyDBAdapter.INFO column then you can retrieve them like this:

```
SmileyHelper.open();

Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getAllSmileys();

if(c!=null)
{
   int i=0;
   info = new int[c.getCount()]();

   //get the column index
   int infoIndex = c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO);

   while(c.moveToNext()){
       String infoItem = c.getString(infoIndex );
       int infoItemInteger = Integer.parseInt(infoItem);
       info[i++] =infoItemInteger;
   }
}

c.close();

SmileyHelper.close();
```

You are storing the image id's in the database as string which is making things more complicated.  There is no need to parse and valueOf the drawable resource ID's into and out of a text column in the database.  Simply change the column type to integer and always work with integers for your images.

You can simply use Cursor.getInt() to retrieve the values.

Comment: those`int`type are marked here as errors, I get this message: Syntax Error on int, Dimesions excepted after this token. -.-

Comment: sorry 'bout that ... int is a simple data type.  Probably better to stick to simply arrays

Comment: incidentally Integer is a wrapper class around int so you could use that.  I've adjusted the answer to use the simple int though

Answer (score 1):

Try create constructor in ImageAdapter

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageIds) {
    mContext = c;
    mThumbIds = imageIds;
}
```

And in `getImagesMethod` replace

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

with

```
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, info));
```

Comment: for `Contect c` you ment `Context c`right? and for `mContexx = c;` you ment `mContect = c;` right?? I changed it but it still dosn't work what am I still doing wrong, sorry im pritty new to Android and Java

Comment: Hello Misses Beloglazov, I updated the code aboth and tried to bring it to work for hours, I still don't get what I'm doing wrong. I still can't compile it... Also i tried just to set `private Integer[] mThumbIds`also didn't work.... :(

Comment: @safari in `getImages` method you create array `picture` array, which contains string `"Info"` and then you try to parse it to number. That's why it throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying this out and found this solution. The only one which worked.

```
public Integer[] getImages(){

        SmileyHelper.open();

        Cursor c = SmileyHelper.getAllSmileys();    

        ArrayList<Integer> infoList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO);
        int ColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(SmileyDBAdapter.INFO);

        if(c!=null)
        {

           while(c.moveToNext()){
               String infoItem = c.getString( ColumnIndex );
               infoList.add(Integer.parseInt(infoItem));
           }
        }

        info = infoList.toArray(new Integer[]{});

        c.close();


        SmileyHelper.close();

        //Hier wird die Grindview gefüllt
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.SmileyGrind);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, info));

        return info;

    }
```

Comment: List may be overkill in this situation. Performance wise you may want to set the initial size of the List to make sure that memory managment isn't ontantly trying to resize for you.